# How do I use an if statement to select and concat values from the same table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, concatenation

flat-on-desk day.

I'm trying to retrieve data in a pre-sorted format from the following, within a MySQL 5.1 database:

```
id | name    | sub
-------------------
1  | cat 1   | 0
2  | cat 2   | 0
3  | cat 3   | 0
4  | sub 1   | 2
```

The 'sub' column above refers to the id of the same table, but as a sub category grouping. I want to be able to essentially export the list, using CONCAT() only when it is a sub category.

Ideally, the final output would be this:

```
id | name
------------------
1  | cat 1
2  | cat 2
4  | cat 2 - sub 1
3  | cat 3
```

My feeble attempts have led me to this hilarious query, to no avail:

```
SELECT c.id AS id,
(case when c.sub > 0 then CONCAT(ca.name, ' - ', c.name) AS name else c.name AS name)
FROM cat c
LEFT JOIN cat ca ON c.sub = ca.id
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Any help would be rewarded with undeniable gratitude, and potentially cookies.

Comment: Note that by convention, we tend to use NULL, not 0, for orphans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is needed here is to `LEFT JOIN` the table against itself to get the category and the sub-category. The `COALESCE()` returns either the concatenated value (which is `NULL` if there's no matching sub-category) or the concatenated value.

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  COALESCE(CONCAT(c.name, '-', s.name), s.name) AS catname
FROM
  cats s
  LEFT JOIN cats c ON s.sub = c.id
ORDER BY catname ASC
```

Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/201b1/8

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to wrap my head around this for hours!